# String strip() not working

Tags: python, python-3.5

I'm new to Python and am having issues stripping excess material off a string that has been converted from a byte array. The code is reading data from a barcode reader and then comparing it to a lookup table read in from a file(the code stores lookup table as an array of lists). The barcode data is kept in a byte array read in from pyserial that I am trying to convert to a string so it can be compared.

File read:

```
with open('LUT.csv', 'rt') as csvfile:
lutFile = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
for line in lutFile:
    # the line is a list, append it to our lutTable list so that
    # when we are done scanning the file we will have the
    # complete list in memory.
    self.lutTable.append(line)
```

Barcode conversion:

```
if gotBarcode:
    # We have received a barcode, see if we recognize it.
    #model               = self.byteArray.decode("utf8") <<-- This does not work either...
    modelString         = str(self.byteArray, encoding='utf-8', errors='strict')
    modelString.strip(' \t\n\r')
    self.modelNumber.config(text="%s" % modelString)
    self.serialCount    = 0
    searchIndex         = 0
    for i in self.lutTable:
        if (modelString == self.lutTable[searchIndex][0]):
            fileName = self.lutTable[i][0]
            break;
        else:
            print("Lut check:%d: model:%s---, table:%s---" %(searchIndex, modelString, self.lutTable[searchIndex][0]))
            fileName = 0;

        searchIndex += 1

    del self.byteArray[:]
    print("%s" % searchIndex)

    if fileName:
        self.FileName.config(text="%s" % fileName)
```

Barcode as seen on the serial port:

---

```
Transfers data from a COM port to a client (COM30) - 13 bytes of 13
    STATUS_SUCCESS
            39 30 30 30 30 42 34 20 20 20 20 20 09            90000B4
```

---

Barcode data as seen from the print in the code which also shows the data from the lookup table:
Read port...

```
Lut check:0: model:90000B4      ---, table:90000B1---
Lut check:1: model:90000B4      ---, table:90000B10---
Lut check:2: model:90000B4      ---, table:90000B2---
```

The barcode data coming in from the serial port is 13 bytes long and it appears that after the conversion from a byte array and attempted strip of spaces, the printed string is still 13 characters wide(it is hard to tell on this post but there are 6 extra characters after the "model:90000B4".) I can't really tell what the extra 6 characters are but they are causing the compare to fail.

Platform specifics: Windows 7, Python 3.5.4

So what is incorrect/missing about the `modelString.strip(' \t\n\r')` line?

Comment: Why not just `.strip()`? We are unable to reproduce your problem unless you post the actual bytes (`[ord(b) for b in self.byteArray]`). You should probably use ascii encoding instead of utf-8.

Comment: Or, if working with bytes - stick with them... byte string's `.strip` works fine... or if being explicit, then using `.strip(b'xyz')` is fine

Comment: Surely though, you'd have either a length or a known delimiter? That way you can tell whether the extra data is start of something else or a "break"...

Comment: FWIW, OP did post the bytes: `39 30 30 30 30 42 34 20 20 20 20 20 09`. In UTF-8, that's five spaces and a tab at the end.

Comment: The fundamental issue is that `strip` doesn't work in-place. `str` objects are immutable, thus, they return new string objects. So you have to assign the result of `my_string.strip`, but fundamentally, there doesn't seem to be any need to convert to `str`, just use the `.strip` method on `bytearray` objects...

Comment: Tried ".strip()" before and it did not work. Also tried Jon C's suggestion of stripping the bytes, but self."byteArray.strip(b'\x40\x09')" does not work.

Comment: Taking juanpa's information I tried to work strictly on the bytearray by removing the spaces(0x40) and the tab(0x09): "self.byteArray = self.byteArray.strip(b'\x40\x09')", had no effect.

Comment: @Jon C. Normally after pulling data directly off the serial port you would go into some type of protocol handler. The barcode reader is configured to just spit data at you so I needed to just grab all of it and remove what I don't want.

Comment: @Paulo. Running the loop "for b in self.byteArray: print (b)" You get the output "57 48 48 48 48 66 52 32 32 32 32 32 9".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign the result of `modelString.strip(' \t\n\r')` back to `modelString` like so:

```
modelString = modelString.strip(' \t\n\r')
```

Comment: This worked as advertised. I also tried the same method "self.byteArray = self.byteArray.strip(b'\x40\x09')" on the byte array suggestion above, but it did not work on that. Thanks...

Comment: Good catch. Strings are immutable in Python, so no string method mutates the string object itself, all methods return a new string or other object - you almost always want to assign the result of `str.method(...)` to some variable.

Comment: Where is `'\x40'` coming from? I don't see that in the byte string. Maybe it's supposed to be `'\x14'`? It might be easier to just use `byteArray.rstrip()`, which will remove all trailing whitespace.

Comment: Thanks Wyatt, that was it. "self.byteArray = self.byteArray.strip(b'\x20\x09')" works. So I'm guessing byte arrays are immutable as well.

Comment: According to the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#binary-sequence-types-bytes-bytearray-memoryview), `bytes` objects are immutable and `bytearray` objects are mutable.

Comment: Using "self.byteArray.strip(b'\x20\x09')" alone did not work which is why I thought bytearray's were not changeable.